# Fixing holes in drywall using glue patches

Tags: adhesive, patching-drywall

Is it ok to use glue patches to fix tiny holes in a drywall? I'm not sure if they will dry out or something. It's look ok to me right now and was very quick and easy to do. They're some kind of adhesive gum that you're able to shape.

[image: Glue patches]

Comment: use white toothpaste

Comment: @jsotola just have this image of someone using a red striped toothpaste :)

Comment: @SolarMike, lol ... they can say that they are from Poland or Switzerland or Japan or Canada and they were feeling patriotic

Comment: @SolarMike   CLOSE-Up

Comment: yeah, that's a good fix. dry-dex would be better, but it's not critical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to hide small holes in Sheetrock and plaster. One is toothpaste as jsotola suggested but some land lords or slum lizards use black lights to find this as tooth paste many times has whiteners, these show up and my friend Got tired of finding crappy hidden fixes. For these small holes most of the time I would say he was an AZZ , then when I saw 1/2” and larger holes I started to understand! 
A bit of joint compound pressed into the spot , maybe watered down a bit to fill the small void is legal and he cannot keep the deposit , but toothpaste he can be identified , my friend just got tired of crappy fixes and toothpaste = no refund of deposit. Just saying. A quart of premixed mud can fill hundreds of nail holes , fill the hole then wipe with a wet sponge. This is the best advice I can give after having several rentals and working for a friend in a college town.

Comment: Plus, if it's his own place he might not be able to paint over it.+

Comment: My deposit was refunded after using glue patches and tippex but the holes were located in places you don't normally look.

Comment: I am glad to hear , I just try to give advice from my experience, I have not seen those glue patches in the past.